# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: status (code 1)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on a project which allows for storing columns from a SQLite database to a list activity, but I am running into an issue with the database.  Specifically I am getting an fatal exception in the android monitor when I run the project which tells me that there is no such column in my database.  Here is the code where I set up the database:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;


public class myDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TB_Student = "student";
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    public static final String MAJOR = "major";

    public myDB(Context contextr) {
        super(contextr, NAME , null , DB_VERSION , null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create Table " + TB_Student + " (" +
                ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                MAJOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                STATUS + "TEXT NOT NULL" + ");");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public Cursor getStudents() {
        String[] cols = new String[] { ID, NAME, MAJOR, STATUS};
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(TB_Student, cols, null, null, null, null, NAME);

    }

    public Cursor getStudent(int studentId) {
        String[] cols = new String[] { ID, NAME, MAJOR, STATUS};
        String sel = ID + "=?";
        String[] selArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(studentId)};
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(TB_Student, cols, sel, selArgs, null, null, null);

    }

    public long numStudents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement("SELECT COUNT(1) " + "FROM "+ TB_Student + ";");
        return st.simpleQueryForLong();

    }

    public long addStudent(String name, String major, String status) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME, name);
        cv.put(MAJOR, major);
        cv.put(STATUS, status);
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.insert(TB_Student, null, cv);

    }

    public boolean delStudent(int studentId) {
        String sel = ID + "=?";
        String[] selArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(studentId) };
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        return (db.delete(TB_Student, sel, selArgs) > 0);
    }

}
```

and here is my mainActivity code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;



public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    myDB newmyDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //newmyDB.addStudent("Mike DiLoreto", "CPE", "2018");

        Button addStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addStudent);
        newmyDB = new myDB(this.getApplicationContext());
        setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_entry, // list_entry.xml
                newmyDB.getStudents(),
                new String [] { myDB.NAME, myDB.MAJOR, myDB.STATUS },
                new int[] { R.id.textViewLeft, R.id.textViewMiddle,     R.id.textViewRight },    // text view IDs here
                0));

        addStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

also, here is the monitor log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1iHe.png

I already tried deleting the app on the emulator and performing a clean build, so I'm not really sure what to do.

Make sure your spaces are correct.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a space after status

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it, I feel like an idiot

Comment: It happens. But please do take the advice of @MikeM.  and only use the images for actual images. Code and error messages (in full) should be added to your post in code blocks.